# Ciclo for en c++ problema para hacer una matriz con nombres de candidatos y sus votos

Tags: c++

El problema es que necesito hacer un programa donde el usuario ingrese el numero de candidatos que se registraron y posteriormente preguntar su nombre y numero de votos que tuvieron para después mostrarlo en pantalla

dejo mi código aquí...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nombre[10][50];
    int i,j,votos,candidatos;
    cout<<"SISTEMA DE CONTABILIZACION DE VOTOS"<<"\n";
    cout<<"¿Cuantos candidatos estan registrados?";
        cin>>candidatos;
    for(i=0;i<candidatos;i++){
        cout<<"\n¿Cual es el nombre del candidato?";
        cin.getline(nombre[i],50);
        for(j=0;j<candidatos;j++){
            cout<<"¿Cuantos votos se registraron de este candidato?";
            cin>>votos;
        }

    }
    for(i=0;i<candidatos;i++){
        cout<<"\n"<<"El nombre del candidato es: "<<nombre[i]<<"\n"<<"Tiene..."<<votos<<"  Votos";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿cual es tu pregunta o problema?

Comment: mi problema es que a la hora de correr el programa no da bien el numero de votos cuando lo muestra y no se muestran de manera correcta la pregunta del nombre del candidato

Comment: ¿Y no crees que esa informacion sea relevante?, por favor colocalo edita tu pregunta y añadelo alli, ademas explica tu estrategia de solucion, te recomiendo leer [ask] y pasar el [tour] si no lo has hecho

Comment: entonces no me vas a ayudar? :c

Comment: ¿No crees que señalarte como hacer una buena pregunta no es una ayuda?, si tu respuesta esta bien explicada mucha gente de la comunidad de ayudara

Comment: @Guillermo ¿No te da bien el número de votos? ¿Cuál es la manera "bien"? ¿Qué datos entras y que datos esperas recibir? ¿No se muestran de manera correcta? ¿Cuál es la manera "correcta"? ¿Qué datos entras y qué datos esperas recibir? Ten en cuenta que no conocemos todos los detalles que para ti pueden estar claros, debes redactar la pregunta con todo lo relevante, por favor **ayúdanos a ayudarte**.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nombre[10][50];
    int votos[10]; 
    int i,j,candidatos;
    cout<<"SISTEMA DE CONTABILIZACION DE VOTOS"<<"\n";
    cout<<"¿Cuantos candidatos estan registrados?";
        cin>>candidatos;
    for(i=0;i<candidatos;i++){
        cout<<"\n¿Cual es el nombre del candidato?";
        cin.ignore(1);
        cin.getline(nombre[i],50);
        cout<<"¿Cuantos votos se registraron de este candidato?";
        cin>>votos[i];
        }

    }
    for(i=0;i<candidatos;i++){
        cout<<"\n"<<"El nombre del candidato es: "<<nombre[i]<<"\n"<<"Tiene..."<<votos[i]<<"  Votos";

    }


     return 0;
}
```

Bueno, primero que todo no se para que usaste el segundo bucle for dentro dentro del bucle de los candidatos, eso solo haría que pidieras n veces el mismo dato, segundo, tu solo estas almacenando los votos del ultimo candidato, así que debes crear un vector para almacenar los votos de cada candidato, y por ultimo aunque es mas técnico, antes de realizar un ***cin.getline(...)*** debes colocar la instrucción ***cin.ignore(1) si y solo si*** antes hay una lectura previa de una variable de tipo int, como en este caso, donde primero preguntas la cantidad de candidatos (tipo int) y luego pides el nombre del candidato *i*, esto debido a un problema con el buffer de entrada que almacena algo asi como un "\n" despues de tomar un dato int